# Poor performance when loading child entities with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I'm building an ASP.Net application with Entity Framework (Code First) and I've implemented a Repository pattern [like the one in this example](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).

I only have two tables in my database. One called `Sensor` and one called `MeasurePoint` (containing only `TimeStamp` and `Value`). A sensor can have multiple measure points. At the moment I have 5 sensors and around 15000 measure points (approximately 3000 points for each sensor).

In one of my MVC controllers I execute the following line (to get the most recent MeasurePoint for a Sensor)

```
DbSet<Sensor> dbSet = context.Set<Sensor>();
var sensor = dbSet.Find(sensorId);
var point = sensor.MeasurePoints.OrderByDescending(measurePoint => measurePoint.TimeStamp).First();
```

This call takes ~1s to execute which feels like a lot to me. The call results in the following SQL query

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[MeasurePointId] AS [MeasurePointId], 
[Extent1].[Value] AS [Value], 
[Extent1].[TimeStamp] AS [TimeStamp], 
[Extent1].[Sensor_SensorId] AS [Sensor_SensorId]
FROM [dbo].[MeasurePoint] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[Sensor_SensorId] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent1].[Sensor_SensorId] = @EntityKeyValue1)
```

Which only takes ~200ms to execute, so the time is spent somewhere else.

I've profiled the code with the help of Visual Studio Profiler and found that the call that causes the delay is

```
System.Data.Objects.Internal.LazyLoadBehavior.<>c_DisplayClass7`2.<GetInterceptorDelegate>b_1(!0,!1)
```

So I guess it has something to do with lazy loading. Do I have to live with performance like this or are there improvements I can make? Is it the ordering by time that causes the performance drop, if so, what options do I have?

**Update:**
I've updated the code to show where `sensor` comes from.

Comment: Is it an execution time of very first call only?

Comment: What type 'sensor' object is of? Is it `DbContext`?

Comment: No, it's a `Sensor` object taken from the `DbContext`. I've updated my question to reflect this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What that will do is load the entire children collection into memory and then perform the .First() linq query against the loaded (appx 3000) children.

If you just want the most recent, use this instead:

`context.MeasurePoints.OrderByDescending(measurePoint => measurePoint.TimeStamp).First();`

Comment: Thank you. This was a lot faster.

Answer (score 1):

If that's the query it's running, it's loading all 3000 points into memory for the sensor.  Try running the query directly on your DbContext instead of using the navigation property and see what the performance difference is.  Your overhead may be coming from the 2999 points you don't need being loaded.